# I have Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference

Tags: php

Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in C:\xampp\htdocs\engine\server_modules\trinity\character.php on line 54

```
    $res = $this->DB->prepare("SELECT guid, name, level, race, class, gender FROM `characters` WHERE `account` = :account ORDER BY level;");
    $res->bindParam(':account', $CURUSER->get('id'), PDO::PARAM_INT); 
    $res->execute();

    if ($res->rowCount() > 0)
    {
        return $res;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

$res->bindParam(':account', $CURUSER->get('id'), PDO::PARAM_INT); <--- ( error line 54 )----

Comment: _$CURUSER->get('id')_ is a method call (kind of a function call here). A function returns a value, but is **not** a variable. Strict standard asks for variables as parameters. So, Adrian P's solution to assign the function result first to a variable and then use this variable to call the _bindParam_ method would work fine. u_mulder's hint, of course would equally be ok, since this method does not ask for variables.

Answer (score 1):

Try to save `$CURUSER->get('id')` into a variable before executing `$res = $this->DB`.

Example: First call `$test = $CURUSER->get('id')` and then bind the `$test` variable:

```
$res->bindParam(':account', $test, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

Answer (score 0):

At these line missing `;`

that is correct:

```
$test = $CURUSER->get('id');
```

Comment: There isn't a missing `;` in the original question, so this isn't an answer. If you have comments about another answer, you should put them in as comments.